# How to find the formula for the partial sum of an infinite series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This problem comes form the Book of Louis Leithold on his "TC7 Calculus" book, it is all about finding the formula for ${s_n}$ or the partial sum of the infinite series,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{5}{(3n+1)(3n-2)}$$

Comment: Hint: what's $\frac{1}{3n-2}-\frac{1}{3n+1}$? Then use [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: Is that from a fraction decomposition?

Comment: Please share your own attempts.